# Nubo vs Nubejo ... Which Word Is Better?

Tags: single-word-requests

This question is about 'the cloud', i.e. the place where one gets something out of a blackbox from the internet. Yes, like Microsoft 365, anything Google, Zoom... everything really that you rely on that is not totally installed on your computer.

I see sometime 'nubo' or 'nubejo'.

In my Esperanto mind, 'nubejo' is better, as is... 'the place in the cloud' where one can find remote managed services. Still in that mindframe, 'nubo' is very different: a visible mist of some kind, whether water vapour or smoky thing.

I am asking: Is there an authoritative source that establishes whether nubo or nubejo is the term to use in an official setting for the meaning that relates to internet?

Comment: Why would komputeko say: cloud = nubo ... while public cloud = publika nubejo ... https://telegramo.org/komputeko/#cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different kind of cloud services, many are such that laymen have never heard of them. Let me list perhaps the five most known ones shortly without going too deeply into the subject. Note that some services fit into several categories, because there are different ways to use them.

- IaaS : infrastructure as a service

You can built your own virtual machine into a cloud. Great flexibility, a lot of work.

- PaaS : platform as a service

You built your application completely into a cloud. Gets one started easily. If you have heard about Google App Engine, it's a PaaS.

- FaaS : functions as a service

You built your application by calling functions that you or someone else have put into a cloud. Allows you combine best of both worlds. AWS Lambda, Google Cloud Functions and  Microsoft Azure Functions are the leading brands.

- SaaS : software as a service

Ready to use software in a cloud. Some are cloud-only, some provide a desktop/mobile device interface to them. Google Apps, iCloud Apps, Dropbox etc.

- StaaS : storage as a service

Storage space for a user to use in the cloud. This is perhaps the most known category. Google Drive, iCloud Drive, Dropbox…

--

I'm afraid that there is no authoritative source, which would have gone through all things what you can do using cloud services and figured out what they should be called in Esperanto. This is again one of things only the community can decide by choosing how to call them.

I have never heard the word *nubejo* before, but it does make sense: a place in the cloud. And that appears to be the reasoning behind Komputeko's choices. As I see it, *nubo* could refer generally to the services and *nubejo* to the place. Therefore one could write:

> Oni uzas la mallongigon *StaaS* (el la angla "storage as a service") por tiaj nubaj servoj, kie la uzanto mem konservas siajn datenojn en nubejon. Tiaj estas ekzemple…

Comment: Viaj komentoj logikas. Mi konsentas pri viaj priskriboj de la variaj nuboj/nubejoj servoj. Kiel vi diris: unu tago, la Eo komunumo devos decidi.

Answer (score 3):

Laŭ mi la vorto estas `nubo`. Nubejo estus ... ĉu ĉielo? ;)